# Работа с API сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, аутентификация

Здравствуйте, мне нужно с с помощью `API` залогиниться на сайте и получить `token`.

### Request

```
POST /api/2.0/authentication.json HTTP/1.1
Host: portal.onlyoffice.com
Accept: application/json,application/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
userName=yourusername&password=yourpassword
```

### Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
    "count": 0,
    "startIndex": 0,
    "status": 0,
    "response": {
    "token": "sdjhfskjdhkqy739459234",
    "expires": "2013-01-13T16:35:42.7564317+04:00"
    }
}
```

Я написал такой код:

```
private async Task<string> Authorize(string userName, string password)
{
     var uri = new Uri("http://portal.onlyoffice.com/api/2.0/authentication");
     var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
     {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
     });

     var client = new HttpClient();
     var response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent);
     var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     dynamic jsonResult = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
     return jsonResult.token;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> LoginInExternal()
{
    var token = await Authorize("email@gmail.com", "password");
    return View();
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после выполнения сервер дает ответ:

> {StatusCode: 402, ReasonPhrase: 'Server error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers}

В чем заключается ошибка и какие возможные варианты решения существуют?

Comment: В данной редакции ваше сообщение не содержит вопроса, а содержит постановку задачи. Конкретизируйте вашу проблему. Для этого попробуйте решить задачу самостоятельно. Начните, например, с изучения класса [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Также рекомендую ознакомиться со страницей справки [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) и с темой [Как отвечать на вопросы про “домашнее задание”?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: */api/2.0/authentication.json* и */api/2.0/authentication* — это разные *url-ы*.